# Initialization of object with existing object of class

Tags: objective-c, class, inheritance

For example we have a task initialize a new object of class with created object earlier.

```
@interface Point
{
  float x;
  float y;
}
@interface Figure2D:Point //for example it can be a foursquare
{
  NSString* nameFigure;
}
@interface Figure3D:figure2D //it will be a cube
{
  float height;
}
```

Next step it's creating cube from square. 
As i understand that we must create a method like this

```
+newFigure3dFromFigure2D:(Figure2D*)_figure2D 
                  height:(float)_height;
```

Is it possible to copy a object in new or converting it to Figure3D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to add a custom method to the superclass and override in each subclass (calling `super` as appropriate). This could perhaps be called `cloneTo:`. The idea being that you create a new instance of your `Figure3D` and then call:

```
[myFigure2DInstance cloneTo:myNewFigure3DInstance];
```

that calls `super`, the `Point` copies in the `x` and `y`, then `Figure2D` copies in the `nameFigure`. After that you can set the `height` and you have a shiny new configured 3D instance.

(this is the same logic as used by the `copy` method but doesn't create the new instance - because it would be of the wrong class type).

Comment: `code`-initWithFiguire2D:(Figure2D*)_figure
{
if((self=_figure2D))
}
`code`
is it a correct?

Comment: To do what? You could have an init method which called `clone:`. Not sure what your `if` statement is about / for / trying to do.

Comment: hmm. i'm trying to continue my realisation for initWithClass:
I'm try your copy method.

Comment: Standard init method with call to super and if to check super returned a valid instance. After that, call `cloneTo:` on the passed instance with `self` as the parameter.